# I want to fetch list of tables from mysql database from nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
connection.query('SHOW tables', function(err, tables){ 
    console.log(tables);
});
```

this query returns :

```
[
  RowDataPacket { Tables_in_books: 'au' },
  RowDataPacket { Tables_in_books: 'authors' },
  RowDataPacket { Tables_in_books: 'customers' },
  RowDataPacket { Tables_in_books: 'persons' },
  RowDataPacket { Tables_in_books: 'user' }
]
```

But i only want the names. i.e. output should be au, authors, cutomers, persons, user.
basically i just need name of tables in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select table_name from information_schema.tables

where table_schema - 'books'

Comment: giving same result as I mentioned earlier

Comment: I think you have to add table_name in function(err, table_name)

Comment: ya and also in console.log.  `console.log(table_name[0].TABLE_NAME);`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a built in database that includes meta data about your databases, this database name is `information_schema`.

So you can query it by doing something as follows

`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema ='Database Name';`

so for you, you can do this

```
connection.query(`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = abc`, function(err, tables){ 
    console.log(tables);
});
```

You can learn more about `information_schema` here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.7/en/

Comment: returns undefined

Comment: give more context please. What is the exact query you used and what is your db setup? what user permissions do you have?

Comment: where table_schema - 'abc' , we have to specify database name within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a javascript problem. All you needed to do was loop through the array being returned and add the value of each object to an array.

```
const result = tables.map(table => table['Table_in_books'])
```

I think this should solve your problem